# How to cluster markers from a locally defined geoJSON?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm trying to do something very similar to [this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markercluster-custom-marker-icons/). However, I've a locally defined geojson `geojson` and a map `map`; my code is as follows :

```
L.mapbox.featureLayer(geojson).on('ready', function(e) {
    var clusterGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
        iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
            return L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                'marker-symbol': cluster.getChildCount(),
             });
        }
    });
    e.target.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
    });
    map.addLayer(clusterGroup);
});
```

I've no erros in the console but I can't see any clusters on the map. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

If by 'locally defined', you mean that `geojson` is simply a variable and will not be loaded, the problem with this code is that it is still using the `.on('ready'` callback. That callback depends on an asynchronous load - when Mapbox.js requests an external resource. Since there's no request, the callback isn't called. Instead, you'd write:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(geojson);
var clusterGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        return L.mapbox.marker.icon({
            'marker-symbol': cluster.getChildCount(),
         });
    }
});
featureLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
});
map.addLayer(clusterGroup);
```